# How to fetch a graph of persistent objects with one database call using JDO API?

Tags: jdo

I have various relations between my entities, and by default all relations use **lazy loading**. I don't want to use eager loading, but I want to be able to **fetch some relation in certain query**. *(Like I can do using **JPA's join fetch**)*

I tried to use named fetch group, but I'm not sure how to work with it. I want to tell JDO to  create **only one sql query with joins**, and then build an entity graph for me.

```
<class name="Account" identity-type="application" table="account" detachable="false" >
            <inheritance strategy="new-table" />
            <field name="_accountId" value-strategy="sequence" sequence="ACCOUNT_ID_SEQUENCE"><column name="account_id" /></field>

            <field name="_phone"><column name="phone" /></field>
            <field name="_phoneCode"><column name="phone_code" /></field>
            <field name="_phone2"><column name="phone2" /></field>
            <field name="_phone2Code"><column name="phone2_code" /></field>
            <field name="_state"><column name="state" /></field>

            <fetch-group name="personInfo">
            <field name="_personHistory" mapped-by="_account" delete-action="cascade">
                <collection element-type="Person" />
                <column name="account_id" />
            </field>
            </fetch-group>


        </class>
```

And the code

```
PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
Query query = pm.newQuery(Account.class);
FetchPlan fetchPlan = pm.getFetchPlan();
fetchPlan.addGroup("personInfo");
fetchPlan.setFetchSize(FetchPlan.FETCH_SIZE_GREEDY);

return (List<Account>) query.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

JDO `FetchGroup`/`FetchPlan` has more flexibility than anything JPA has to offer IMHO.

You define fetch groups for persistable classes following [this link](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jdo/persistence.html#fetch_groups). So you can put particular fields in a `FetchGroup`. And then you add that fetch group to the `FetchPlan`. In the case of a query you set the FetchPlan of the query to include all fields of the candidate (and related objects) that you want to retrieve, as per http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jdo/query.html#FetchPlan

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have already tried to do this, but after query.execute() I'll get only fileds, that belong to default fetch group, and the rest ones are null

Comment: Could you please take a look at the code I have added?

Comment: why are you defining collection etc under <fetch-group> ? <fetch-group> is to define WHICH FIELDS and nothing else.

Comment: Hah, okay, I see. What to do if I need to load related collection?

Comment: you put _the collection field_ in the fetch group!

Comment: what do you mean? Is the provided code is incorrect?

Comment: You put _<field name="myCollectionField"/>_. You do not put all of the sub-XML elements, as the JDO spec would tell you

Comment: Okay, could you edit your answer and show a code snippet with xml, how it should be if I want to load an account with the related _personHistory collection, using one database call?

Comment: The first link I provide gives you an example with xml. And you will NEVER be guaranteed "1 database call" because no persistence solution can generate SQL that fetches everything in one call (at least not for multi-valued fields). It guarantees that the field WILL be loaded. As shown in the LOG of your provider

Comment: I've tried various examples, and it still not working, probably because it's DataNucleus 2 :( I need to be sure that it performs only one call to get a parent and one child, because I'm looping over a list of entities and I want to avoid n+1 select ptoblem

Comment: that version hasn't been supported since 2010 IIRC!! either way this answers HOW you fetch fields from a JDO query.